# In JMeter, Is it possible to modify the image and upload without saving to filesystem?

Tags: image, jmeter

We have a requirement to upload a new image for every request to the REST API call in Load test with JMeter. So In JMeter, Is it possible to read the image from the file system, and change few bytes and upload without saving to the filesystem?

Appreciate any input. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is, but:

1. You will have to write code for amending the image on the fly in memory using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) language and sending the image to your server using [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/examples/org/apache/http/examples/entity/mime/ClientMultipartFormPost.java) yourself
2. You won't be able to get the benefit of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (and all related configuration elements like [Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), [Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager/), etc.) so if your test plan contains any of these - consider the extra effort required to make your Groovy code aware of the virtual user context (embedded resources, headers, cookies, cache, etc.)

---

Why don't you just delete the image after the upload using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) or [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, even when using the HttpClient, File content is taken from the physical file (by name) and doesn't see the possibility to use on the fly modified image content. Can you please share any idea to upload on the fly modified content?

FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(args[0]));